# wix:assembly attribute of file element

Tags: wix

Is it necessary to have assembly = .net in file element?

Answer (score 5):

No, you only specify ".net" or "win32" if you want the file to be added to the Global Assembly Cache. Choose "No" otherwise, this is the default.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_file.htm

Answer (score -1):

The assembly attribute of the file element must either be ".net" or "win32".

See http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_file.htm for more detail.